# Why does my code think that canvas functions are undefined in my constructor's prototype in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas, constructor, prototype

I have a constructor, `Chomp`, which creates a canvas element; its property that has the canvas element is `this.c`, but when I try to call functions on `this.c` in a method of my constructor, I receive an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginPath' of undefined (line 28 in function Chomp.chomping)`. I need to know why this is and how to fix this problem. Below is the part of my code important to this problem.

**Update:** It is the second time through the animate function that `this.c` becomes undefined, so, my error must be in the method `Chomp.prototype.animate`.

```
var Chomp = function(x, y) {
  /*many properties*/
  this.element = document.createElement("canvas");
  this.c = this.element.getContext("2d");
  /*a few more properties*/
}
Chomp.prototype.chomping = function() {
  /*some conditions,... properties like this.width were defined in Chomp, 
  but omitted because of their lack of importance to the question.*/
  this.c.clearRect(/*arguments*/);
  this.c.beginPath();
  this.c.moveTo(/*arguments*/);
  this.c.arc(/*arguments*/);
  this.c.lineTo(/*arguments*/);
  this.c.lineTo(/*arguments*/);
  this.c.fillStyle = "yellow";
  this.c.fill();
  /*more conditions*/
}
Chomp.prototype.animate = function() {
  Chomp.prototype.chomping.apply(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    Chomp.prototype.animate.apply(this);
  }, 50);
}
var yellow = new Chomp(30, 60);
Chomp.prototype.animate.apply(yellow);
```

Comment: How are you calling the `chomping` method?

Comment: where is `this.element` defined?

Comment: When do you execute this code? What is `this.element` at time of execution?

Comment: i call it with my instance like this: `Chomp.prototype.chomping.apply(yellow)'`  yellow would be the instance

Comment: this.element is defined in Chomp

Comment: `Chomp.prototype.chomping.apply(yellow)` Is yellow a Chomp instance with `c`?

Comment: @JavaScriptArray What is `yellow`, and why do you call it this way?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, yellow would be an instance of Chomp, an object created by the constructor

Comment: @Mouser, yes, yellow is an instance of Chomp, and c is one of the properties.

Comment: The error doesn't say the function is undefined, it says `this.c` is undefined. So the problem seems to be with how you're setting `c`.

Comment: Please add the code that sets `this.c` to the question.

Comment: @Barmar, `this.c` is defined in my Constructor function as `this.c = this.element.getContext("2d");` and `this.element` is `this.element = document.createElement("canvas");`

Comment: Try adding `console.log(this.c)` in the constructor.

Comment: @Barmar, console.log returns `CanvasRenderingContext2D{textBaseline: "alphabetic", …}`

Answer (score 0):

```
Chomp.prototype.animate = function() {
  Chomp.prototype.chomping.apply(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    Chomp.prototype.animate.apply(this);
  }, 50);
}
```

setTimeout thinks that this refers to the window object, or the global object, so I needed to define a new variable, like `that` and set it equal to `this` so that the argument in my function in setTimeout was `that`, like so:

```
Chomp.prototype.animate = function() {
  Chomp.prototype.chomping.apply(this);
  var that = this;
  setTimeout(function(){;
    Chomp.prototype.animate.apply(that);
  }, 50);
}
```